# Help creating a bulletin or notice type object

Tags: apex, custom-object, contact, opportunity-lineitem, massemailmessage

So I have a conundrum that I can't figure out.

I need to mass email a list of contacts based upon their account. The only way I can get the Account is by searching OpportunityLineItems by Product and then Opportunities by 'Closed Won'.

I can write Apex Code to get the list of members for each Product (by looking up the Account ID and then looping through the contacts within the account) that I want to filter by, but that will not be user friendly if I have to repeat.

Question is, what would be a good way to accomplish this. I was thinking about using a custom object (or a junction object), maybe calling it Bulletin and that would relate to Contacts, but the tricky part would be filtering those. I may have to run a batch that would associate each contact to a particular bulletin. I'm assuming then I would have create a triggers on Opportunities going forth to update related lists and objects.

Doesn't really seem to be an easy way, so I'm looking for the best approach.

Thanks,

A

Comment: It seems like you want a list of contacts who've purchased a certain product? You can traverse with apex and keep track of relationships with maps in apex. You shouldn't need a separate object as I read it.

Comment: Well, the issue is that I need to get the list of contacts based up a Product they purchased with the Opportunity as Closed Won. I'm able to Map the Opportunity and get an account list, but from that point I need to get the list of the contacts in each of those accounts. From what I see there is no direct relationship from Opportunities to Contacts, so I need to bridge them. I could be over-thinking it, but that seems to be the tricky part. Some Account Contacts may need to be a part of multiple bulletins. Sorry, if this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, you need to transverse quite a few objects, and this is all entirely possible within apex using maps. It is not easy, agreed, but possible.

Comment: Can you say more about the email process you wish to drive? Are you trying to create an email from apex?

Comment: Basically, what we are trying to do this. Let's say we have a product called VMS and there is a now a new update to this product (which is a software). We want to send a notification to all the contacts within the Accounts with Opportunities that are Closed Won. In this case there are probably 1000 accounts with a total of 3000 contacts we would need to send email too. We also have other products where we would need to do the same thing, so if an account owns multiple products, we need a way identify that.

Comment: How about creating a campaign for each product and a trigger or batch to add all contacts to that campaign who've purchased the product. That gives you a ready made email list for each product.

Comment: Ah, that would be make sense. I may need a one time batch to add contacts to the campaign, but then I could use a trigger going forth on contacts to update thereafter. Thanks, I think that is probably the best solution. One tricky thing might be removing users from a campaign, but I would have to build that into the trigger.

Comment: Hopefully you are aware that the governor limit for emailing non-users is pretty low at max 1000 a day and have an alternative way of sending the email? (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm)

Comment: I'm aware. This is going to be tricky, I'm sure.

Comment: So, an idea I had would be to create a VF page that allows you select a query based on a product (in a drop-down) and then from there you can add the query members to a campaign. I wouldn't need to display the members, I could just add them to the campaign with a button. Only issue would be the governor limit. I may have to break down queries into multiple queries, not sure yet.